# How to set session timeout in <glassfish-web-app> / glassfish-web.xml configuration file?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I'm trying to set session timeout in `<glassfish-web-app>` / `glassfish-web.xml` configuration file, but it is not working (using glassfish4 and NetBeans):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">

    <context-root>/some-path</context-root>

    <class-loader delegate="true"/>

    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</glassfish-web-app>
```

But if I create ./WEB-INF/web.xml file like below, everything works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

So, but there are two conf. files: `glassfish-web.xml` and `web.xml`. Can I somehow do all that in just one `glassfish-web.xml` file?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">

    <context-root>/some-path</context-root>

    <class-loader delegate="true"/>

    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-properties>
            <property name="timeoutSeconds" value="600"/>
            <property name="enableCookies" value="false"/>
        </session-properties>
    </session-config>

</glassfish-web-app>
```